# How can I use $mergeObjects with an optional property?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm writing an aggregation below. The purpose of the aggregation is to replace the value of targetedProperty, but *only* if targetedProperty already exists, targetedProperty being an optional property on objectToUpdate.

How would I adjust this code to do this?

```
{
    $set: {
        objectToUpdate: {
            $mergeObjects: [
                '$objectToUpdate',
                {
                    targetedProperty: {
                        $cond: {
                             if: { $lte: ['$objectToUpdate.targetProperty', null] }, 
                             then: undefined, 
                             else: 'newValue'
                        }
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

This is an example of an input:

```
{ otherProperty: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue' }
```

This is my expected result:

```
{ otherProperty: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue' }
```

This is my actual result:

```
{ otherProperty: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue', targetedProperty: null }
```

Note: I do have to do this as an aggregation because I am making use of additional aggregation operators in parts of the logic not shown here.

Comment: Does the documentation outlined here not capture the behavior you're looking for? Either this section or the examples? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#behavior

Comment: I haven't found any specific application of those docs here. "$mergeObjects ignores null operands" did appear promising to me, because if I can make the entire $mergeObjects second array value equal to null, then it would be ignored, but I can't figure out how to do that. I thought that making targetedProperty equal undefined would drop the property from the object, but it seems to be instead making the targetedProperty equal to null instead, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order of your `$cond`, we first check if the field "`targetedProperty"` exists, if it doesn't we'll put the empty object `{}` for the `$mergeObjects` operator, meaning we won't update the object at all, If the field does exists then we'll just put the relevant value, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $set: {
    objectToUpdate: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$objectToUpdate",
        {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$objectToUpdate.targetedProperty",
                undefined
              ]
            },
            {},
            {
              targetedProperty: 123
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qc0yY8JG1Pc)

Comment: This is perfect. I kept the $lte line that I'm using because it targets both null and undefined, but restructured my code based on yours and it does exactly what I want. 

My mistake was that in attempting to use $cond as a base level property in the object, I also had other base level non-operator properties in the same object, which threw an error. Once $cond is the only property in that object, it works, which makes sense. Thank you!